# NHibernate: Multiple Transactions on a single session

Tags: c#, .net, database, nhibernate, rdbms

I want to know if there is any issue by creating several transactions on a single session, like this:

```
using (var session = factory.OpenSession())
{
    using (var trans1 = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        .....
        trans1.commit();
    }

    using (var trans2 = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        .....
        trans2.commit();
    }

    using (var trans3 = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        .....
        trans3.commit();
    }

    using (var trans = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        .....
        // trans1.commit();
    }
}
```

is that possible or must I open a new session object per transaction?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes what you are doing is just fine.

What nhibernate does not support are multiple nested transactions.

Answer (score 1):

It is not usual to have multiple transactions on a single session even in NHibernate. Also from personal experience I can say it is not a good idea to reuse sessions in any other situation.

I recommend to keep the workflow as simple as possible to avoid any side-effects:

- open session
- open transaction
- use your entities
- commit transaction
- rollback in case of exception
- close/flush session (always)

Answer (score 0):

The most common strategy in a web environment is to have session per request.
When it cones to transactions, it really depends on your use-case.
 What you are doing is fine, or otherwise nhibernate wouldn't separate session from transaction.
but yet again, it depends on your business case situation.

I suggest you to wrap the `session.BeginTransaction()` with `IDisposable`, so on `Dispose` you make sure to commit transaction .

Answer (score 0):

No issues although it's unusual. Bear in mind that the session should be discarded if any of the transactions rolls back.

Answer (score 0):

One thind I´d further like to add to this discussion, is that NHibernate cannot handle overlapping Transactions, **even if they come from different Sessions** (global DB Server and local DB file for example).
So for Synchronization you always need to create a real Instance of your Objects and cannot pass them by Query.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34369948)